# How to deploy an ASP.NET project so that there is no code in the .aspx files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I've recently become the maintainer of an ASP.NET web project. In the course of deploying some changes, we noticed that at some point the way the project deploys has changed. The project is a web application project. Currently, when I "Publish" it to my local machine, I can open the various .aspx files and see some code--a little ASP, mostly JavaScript, but the majority of the code seems to be compiled into a .dll.

What we would like is to build and deploy this application so that there is no code in the .aspx files--this is how it used to work, before the previous dev stopped maintaining it. There should be no code in the .aspx files at all, just a reference to the compiled .dll files.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about and how to set it up?

**EDIT** If it helps, it looks like the older version of the app just had text in the .aspx files that said "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!" That is what I'm going for.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what kind of code you are seeing in your .aspx pages?

Comment: I'm thinking that code has always been there and no one knew it

Comment: that seems likely. the main tipoff to management is that there were directories (like "Controls") in the new published directory that weren't there previously.

Comment: in the .aspx files, i'm seeing javascript and code like <asp:Content ID="UiContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server"> - more stuff from the .aspx than from the .aspx.cs files.

Comment: @SuperNES: this is how ASP.NET works - there is no way of getting rid of `<asp:>` tags (unless you're planning to port the whole site to ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: @SuperNES, were you able to get this working with a precompile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this for your Website just Pre-compile your project for deployment only. You can check out the exact steps in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This will move all the codebehind files into the .dll and create .aspx.compiled files as pointers to the compiled versions in the .dll. Sounds like thats what was being done before.

Comment: looks like that might be what i want. i'll try it out and report back.

Comment: SuperNES has not specified if it is a Web Application Project or a Website Project...

Comment: @SuperNES @TJ Kellie - Publishing is a method of pre-compilation. This doesn't have anything with code placement.  Published websites maintain the front end asp.net code in the aspx.  Only the code behind gets compiled into assemblies.  In fact, you can still make updates to the aspx pages.  See a longer explanation in my post.

Comment: @Brian, Publishing from the IDE build menu option is a flavor of pre-compile yes. However dig deeper than the IDE clicking options and you will find all sorts of other flavors from the command line are available.

Comment: The linked MSDN article is 404.

Comment: MSDN link is working, must have been a temporary linking issue when they archived the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The code shouldn't be visible from the client's browser.

Any code that in a code-behind will get compiled to a `.dll` which the pages in the application would reference.  The actual code-behind files shouldn't get published with the `.aspx` files.

.NET code within the `.aspx` files shouldn't be visible on the client-side because it has no use on the client-side.  It should be executed on the server-side to render HTML output to the client.  If the .NET code is visible on the client-side in this case, it means the server isn't executing it and the site is essentially broken.

JavaScript code, of course, *needs* to be visible on the client-side.  There are ways to obfuscate it, but the browser needs to see it in order to execute it.  So in this case that code should be developed with the full understanding that it *is* publicly visible and nothing proprietary or compromising should be included in it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code has to exist on the client side, so that has to be on the server.  Inline ASP code?  I'd look into rewriting that into .NET.

Comment: In fact he's probably talking about inline *ASP.NET* code (which is already in .NET, by definition).

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve no code in the .aspx files you need to write all the code in the code behind.  You use the asp.net events in the life cycle to perform the generation of client code. For example, dynamically generated HTML and javascript could be generated in the Page_Load and written out as a [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Any asp.net that you may use needs to be dynamically generated in the code behind with everything else.

You will still push HTML and javascript to the client, but all the code will be in assemblies/dll's except the header info in the aspx pages.  I have only done this in the context of a web service ( [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)) where I pushed out XML to an iPhone for consumption.  Doing it for a full website may prove to be quite cumbersome.

It doesn't make sense to do this if the concern is security.  Moving the code to an assembly is not much more secure than the aspx page.  If the concern is to remain concise, I suggest moving to ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: Hi Brian,

Can you explain to me why it's not much more secure?  I always get bugged by my superiors to put something as simple as 8 lines of inline c# code in a DLL because it's "more secure", and I'd really love to not have to.  

Thanks!